# gdalwarp : I lose some pixels when I crop

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, sentinel-2

My problem: When I crop with gdal

```
gdalwarp -te minX minY maxX maxY input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

I expect an output shape of (maxX - minX, maxY - minY) = (10980,10980)

BUT : I get an output shape of (10972,10972), why ?

I'm using sentinel-2 bands rasters.jp2 (10980x10980)
I have the ground truth.tif for all the France territory (127001x119574)

Here is the gdalinfo of:
the sentinel_band :

```
Size is 10980, 10980
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
        AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32631"]]
Origin = (399960.000000000000000,4900020.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=3 (pixels/cm)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=0.393701
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=0.393701
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  399960.000, 4900020.000) (  1d44'49.27"E, 44d14'47.56"N)
Lower Left  (  399960.000, 4790220.000) (  1d46' 2.91"E, 43d15'29.34"N)
Upper Right (  509760.000, 4900020.000) (  3d 7'20.12"E, 44d15'12.07"N)
Lower Right (  509760.000, 4790220.000) (  3d 7'12.94"E, 43d15'53.02"N)
Center      (  454860.000, 4845120.000) (  2d26'21.31"E, 43d45'27.90"N)
Band 1 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 5490x5490, 2745x2745, 1372x1372, 686x686
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
Band 2 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 5490x5490, 2745x2745, 1372x1372, 686x686
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
Band 3 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 5490x5490, 2745x2745, 1372x1372, 686x686
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
```

The groundtruth raster:

```
Size is 126813, 119159
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["RGF93 / Lambert-93",
    GEOGCS["RGF93",
        DATUM["Reseau_Geodesique_Francais_1993",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6171"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4171"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",49],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",44],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46.5],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",700000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",6600000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2154"]]
Origin = (51639.688541929819621,7150786.697153925895691)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   51639.689, 7150786.697) (  6d15'27.28"W, 51d 6'36.20"N)
Lower Left  (   51639.689, 5959196.697) (  4d37'17.57"W, 40d27'20.57"N)
Upper Right ( 1319769.689, 7150786.697) ( 11d51'10.22"E, 51d 8'21.82"N)
Lower Right ( 1319769.689, 5959196.697) ( 10d17'14.68"E, 40d28'47.56"N)
Center      (  685704.689, 6554991.697) (  2d48'53.90"E, 46d 5'40.42"N)
Band 1 Block=126813x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

You can see that these two rasters does not have the same SCR.
So, first, I "gdalwarped" my whole groudtruth raster :

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -overwrite grd_truth.tif grd_truth_new_coord.tif
```

when I gdalinfo grd_truth_**new_coord**.tif :

```
Size is 127001, 119574
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32631"]]
Origin = (-149837.580251255538315,5702936.253638198599219)
Pixel Size = (10.007235564303896,-10.007235564303896)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -149837.580, 5702936.254) (  6d17'28.11"W, 51d 6'26.54"N)
Lower Left  ( -149837.580, 4506331.068) (  4d39'36.81"W, 40d27'11.33"N)
Upper Right ( 1121091.344, 5702936.254) ( 11d53' 7.96"E, 51d 8'20.97"N)
Lower Right ( 1121091.344, 4506331.068) ( 10d19'26.60"E, 40d28'30.23"N)
Center      (  485626.882, 5104633.661) (  2d48'50.61"E, 46d 5'42.46"N)
Band 1 Block=127001x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

**Then**, I crop in this freshly re-coordinated groundtruth with my tiles coordonates:

```
gdal warp -te 399960.000 4790220.000 509760.000 4900020.000 re_coord_grdtruth.tif tile_associate_grd_truth.tif
```

The idea is to superpose my sentinel tile and the associated groundtruth

But, I get a shape of (10972,10972) for the cropped-re-coordinated groundtruth
instead of (10980,10980) :

```
Size is 10972, 10972
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32631"]]
Origin = (399960.000000000000000,4900020.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.007291286912141,-10.007291286912141)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  399960.000, 4900020.000) (  1d44'49.27"E, 44d14'47.56"N)
Lower Left  (  399960.000, 4790220.000) (  1d46' 2.91"E, 43d15'29.34"N)
Upper Right (  509760.000, 4900020.000) (  3d 7'20.12"E, 44d15'12.07"N)
Lower Right (  509760.000, 4790220.000) (  3d 7'12.94"E, 43d15'53.02"N)
Center      (  454860.000, 4845120.000) (  2d26'21.31"E, 43d45'27.90"N)
Band 1 Block=10972x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

And I cant find the solution... I didn't try to convert my tile to a .tif raster but I think it is useless.

Comment: Your Pixel Size also grew from 10.000 to 10.007. Maybe your final raster covers the same area as your original with slightly fewer rows and columns but slightly larger pixels. I can't explain it, but I'm not surprised by these small numerical differences after a gdalwarp. Perhaps you could specify more output parameters than just the extent.

Comment: Have a try by giving also the resolution with `-tr 10 10`.

Comment: Yes, at the end, i have the same area covered , i'll try @user30184 advice and i come back.

Comment: Ty very much, it solve my problem.